# Jquery - Target 1 div with .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, target

This might be a beginners question, but I'm at a loss.

My objective is to have a button that when pressed the class that the button was in does something... if that makes sense.. Here is my code for my content on the page:

```
if(domain == 'google.com') {
$('#content').append('<div id="highlight"><h1 id="headline">'+title+'</h1><img id="dropDown" src="images/small-dropdown.png" alt=""/><img class="card" src="'+URL+'"/></div></br>');
$('.card').hide();     
}
```

So that code loops about 25 times and then in my `content` div I have a nice list of the sites I want.
My next piece of code is:

```
$("#dropDown").click(function() {
    $('.card').toggle();
});
```

The problem I am having is that when I press on the `dropDown` button the image `card` is supposed to appear for only 1 div, instead, images are showing up for each div, and I just want to target the div that the button was in. How would I do that?

Comment: since the element is added dynamically, you may have to look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Also IDs must be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#content').on('click', "#dropDown", function() {
    $(this).next('.card').toggle(); //Use next()
});
```

As you are generating elements dynamically. You should use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

Also Important: **IDs must be unique**, So I would suggest you to use class selector like

To generate element use

```
if(domain == 'google.com') {
$('#content').append('<div id="highlight"><h1 id="headline">'
 + title +'</h1><img class="dropDown" src="images/small-dropdown.png" alt=""/><img class="card" src="'+URL+'"/></div></br>');
$('.card').hide();     
}
```

Event Binding

```
$('#content').on('click', ".dropDown", function() {
    $(this).next('.card').toggle(); //Use next()
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The image isn't even being shown now when I press dropDown.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind event to dynamically generated elements, you should use `.on()`:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

It also works for non-generated elements.

Answer (score -1):

It is bad thing to have more than one element with the same id, but you can use something like this:

```
$("#dropDown").click(function() {
   $(this).find('.card').toggle();
});
```

Comment: That didn't work. The image didn't show up... What could I have done wrong?